# Preserve git --assume-unchanged files between branch checkouts

Tags: git

I've been using `git --assume-unchanged yacs/settings/development.py` to ignore my local database configuration file in my dev branch. But when I want to switch branches (for deployments), I get an error that I still have changes pending:

```
% git checkout production
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    yacs/settings/development.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Which is annoying. The only way I know how to get around this would be to stash it:

```
% git stash
% git checkout production
% git merge dev
% ./deploy.sh
% git checkout dev
% git stash pop
# On branch dev
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   yacs/settings/development.py
#
```

But now it's back in the index again (ugh)! Is there a better alternative to this workflow?

[I don't particularly care if the local changes stay locally (aka, it's ok if it's the production branch), I just don't want it pushed to a remote repository.]

Comment: this does not work for me. I add the file with --skip-worktree and git status does not show. However, I am still not able to switch to another branch. What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try ([git update-index man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-update-index)):

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- path
```

> Skip-worktree bit can be defined in one (long) sentence: When reading an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead.

However, as mentioned in "[git assume unchanged vs skip worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138076/git-assume-unchanged-vs-skip-worktree)":

> Both options have problems. `--assume-unchanged` resets itself whenever the index gets discarded (e.g. `git reset`), so that will probably trip you up sooner or later. Same goes for `--skip-worktree`.

---

Plus, make sure to use Git 2.24 (Q4 2014).
Since 2012 (the OP's  question), `git stash` has been ported to C (it is no longer a shell script) but it had (in its new implementation) to (re-)learn to write refreshed index back to disk.

See [commit 34933d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34933d0eff5d4c91fae6ad6f71a6e6a69a496ced) (11 Sep 2019) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Thomas Gummerer -- `tgummerer` --](https://github.com/tgummerer) in [commit 34933d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34933d0eff5d4c91fae6ad6f71a6e6a69a496ced), 20 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `stash`: make sure to write refreshed cache
>
> When converting stash into C, calls to '`git update-index --refresh`'
>   were replaced with the '`refresh_cache()`' function.
>   That is fine as long as the index is only needed in-core, and not re-read from disk.
>
> However in many cases we do actually need the refreshed index to be written to disk, for example '`merge_recursive_generic()`' discards the in-core index before re-reading it from disk, and in the case of '`apply --quiet`', the '`refresh_cache()`' we currently have is pointless without writing the index to disk.
>
> Always write the index after refreshing it to ensure there are no regressions in this compared to the scripted stash.
>   In the future we can consider avoiding the write where possible after making sure none of the subsequent calls actually need the refreshed cache, and it is
>   not expected to be refreshed after stash exits or it is written somewhere else already.

---

Warning, that index might *not* be correctly rewritten when git stash is used with `--quiet`: With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), Recent update to "[`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) pop" made the command *empty* the index when run with the "`--quiet`" option, which has been corrected.

See [commit df53c80](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df53c80822735ddd30638ba77be3face438d5ad8) (13 Nov 2019) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3c3e5d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c3e5d0ea2158bdc4f2244adff08504e50653d7c), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df53c80822735ddd30638ba77be3face438d5ad8): make sure we have a valid index before writing it
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Grzegorz Rajchman</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Thomas Gummerer</sup>
>
> In '`do_apply_stash()`' we refresh the index in the end.
>
> Since [34933d0eff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34933d0eff5d4c91fae6ad6f71a6e6a69a496ced) ("`stash`: make sure to write refreshed cache", 2019-09-11, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba2d45112224a0bd5ba0f10ba180c88d148cec36) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b744c3af07a15aaeb1b82fab689995fd5528f120)), we also write that refreshed index when `--quiet` is given to '[`git stash apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)'.
>
> However if '`--index`' is not given to '[`git stash apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)', we also discard the index in the `else` clause just before.
>
> We need to do so because we use an external 'git update-index --add --stdin', which leads to an out of date in-core index.
>
> Later we call '`refresh_and_write_cache`', which now leads to writing the discarded index, which means we essentially write an empty index file.
>
> This is obviously not correct, or the behaviour the user wanted.
>
> We should not modify the users index without being asked to do so.
>
> Make sure to re-read the index after discarding the current in-core index, to avoid dealing with outdated information.
>
> Instead we could also drop the '`discard_cache()`' + '`read_cache()`', however that would make it easy to fall into the same trap as [34933d0eff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34933d0eff5d4c91fae6ad6f71a6e6a69a496ced) did, so it's better to avoid that.
>
> We can also drop the '`refresh_and_write_cache`' completely in the quiet case.
>
> Previously in legacy stash we relied on '`git status`' to refresh the index after calling '`git read-tree`' when '`--index`' was passed to '`git apply`'.
>
> However the '`reset_tree()`' call that replaced '`git read-tree`' always passes options that are equivalent to '`-m`', making the refresh of the index unnecessary.

Comment: Having tried both `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree`, both continue to complain about uncommitted changes to the file when I try to switch local branches after setting this property.

Comment: @amoe and that file was already versioned right? What if you add that file to `your_repo\.git\info\exclude`?

Comment: @VonC , script.js file have `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree` but still getting same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Eray not just on top of my head. It is best to make a new question with a link back to this one.

Comment: @VonC , asked it on here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549318/not-possible-to-switch-branch-after-skip-worktree thank you.

Comment: @VonC this does not work for me. I add the file with --skip-worktree and git status does not show. However, I am still not able to switch to another branch. What am I missing?

Comment: @san not sure: it would be best to ask a separate question with the guy version, and the exact command you typed.

Comment: @VonC Thanks. It is pretty much what Eray asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549318/not-possible-to-switch-branch-after-skip-worktree

Comment: @sandyp Then it is best to untrack that file completely (`git rm --cached -- afile`, in both branches, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549545/6309), and if possible generates its content through a content filter driver, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45025658/6309.

Answer (score 3):

What I've started doing is creating a branch off master called private that has my local changes; think of it as a proxy branch between my work branch and master. I can rebase my current work branch against private when I need my local-only changes and I have a couple of aliases in my .gitconfig that automate keeping private up-to-date with master. When I need to merge to master, my aliases make sure to rebase --onto master private my work branch first.

I posted a blog entry about this in more detail here http://blog.ericwoodruff.me/2013/02/git-private-branch-pattern.html

Comment: The link in your comment doesn't work, but I like the idea described in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I put the corrected blog link in the original answer

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was to use --skip-worktree.  However, like some above, I struggled with being able to switch between a ticketed branch and the main branch without git complaining even after I had set the --skip-worktree flag on the file whose changes I wanted to remain local.

It seems like you'll run into this issue if you make changes to the local-only file before running --skip-worktree, which is what happened to me.

One suggested workaround, above, is to add the file to `your_repo/.git/info/exclude`.  But I didn't want to add the file to the exclude list, so I did the following from within my working tree directory:

1. `cp <local-only_file> ~/`

   - copy file that has your local-only changes to somewhere safe on the filesystem
2. `git checkout <local-only_file>`

   - in working tree, checkout file so that it matches master branch file
3. `git update-index --skip-worktree -- <local-only_file>`
4. `cp ~/<local-only_file> .`

   - copy file in question from safe location back into working tree
5. `git diff`

   - no changes should be shown; if you push to the main repo, no changes in `<local-only_file>` are included in the push

Answer (score 1):

this issue happens when the skipped file is not same as the one in the branch you are trying to checkout or the one you are trying to pull.