# git stash save assume changed file

Tags: git, git-stash

I changed a tracked file.

I then marked the file with `--assume-unchanged` flag.

I ran `git stash save`, but nothing stashed.

How to stash save assume changed file?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you have run

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

And it looks like you will have to add it to index again before stash it.

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and run git stash *before* marking it "`--assume-unchanged`".
Or at least mark it "`--no-assume-unchanged`" before stashing it.

(unless you are talking about *two* different files, and your question is about the side effect of marking one file "unchanged" and seeing the *other* file *not* picked up by the stash).

---

Note that [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) has been ported to C since 2013, and [using Git 2.24+ (Q4 2019) is advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816844/6309).