# How do I checkout a given revision except a folder and then go back to previous state?

Tags: git, version-control

My aim is, given a list of revisions hash tags, compare their performances on a single test.

The test would be placed in a folder in the same repository and would have not to change as I checkout different revisions (that all know they need to run the test there).

My initial idea was to get the current hash using the first line of `git log`, then `git checkout <hash>` and then `git checkout <current-hash> <folder>`, run the test, then `git checkout <current-hash>`. But then this causes all kinds of problems with files inside `<folder>` which are not in older revisions.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly low-tech, but copy the test folder off somewhere, update, copy the test folder back.  Rinse and repeat for each revision you'd like to test.

Answer (score 0):

Taking example on "[Preserve `git --assume-unchanged` files between branch checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9815416/6309)", you could try and set:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- path/to/your/test/script
```

Then you should be able to checkout any SHA1 for your repo, and it should ignore and leave alone your test script.
(to cancel: `git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- path/to/your/test/script`)