# Prevent git from removing files on checkout

Tags: git

I accidentally indexed a config file that shouldn't be indexed in git.

To remove it, I added it to my `.gitignore` file and did :

```
git rm --cached myfile.conf
```

Now, when I checkout a previous commit (before the deletion) and that I come back to my previous HEAD, git remove myfile.conf from my local file system.

How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to skip the file ([`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)):

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- myfile.conf
```

That should be [preserved during checkout as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816844/6309).

If that doesn't work, try the alternative:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- myfile.conf
```

Comment: It seems to work. Do I have to do this on all my repositories ?

Comment: @DorianMarchal It is local to the repo cloned on your disk. So if you have multiple copies of that repo, each one needs to skip that file.