# configuring existing git repo for sparse checkout

Tags: git

Is it possible to configure an existing local clone of a git repository for sparse checkout?

[Existing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository#) points to performing `git init` and `git remote add -f origin <repo>` which results in long download times for my situation.

I already have a repository locally and I just want to configure it for sparse checkout and then switch to a particular branch.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You still can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909267/2253302

But you should skip some steps (i.e `git init` and `git remote add -f origin <repo>`). I check this steps for my test repo:

1. Enable sparseCheckout in your repo: `git config core.sparseCheckout true`
2. Add path for sparseCheckout `echo testSparseCheckout > .git/info/sparse-checkout`
3. Checkout to your desired branch

This scenario works for me well on my small testing git repo.

Comment: Yes - that's where I started. If "testSparseCheckout" is a folder, it won't check out all of the child files and folders inside of it. I've tried adding / and /* at the end. I does check out some child items but not all.