# git sparse-checkout existing repo serially

Tags: git, github, git-sparse-checkout

Here is what I am doing

***First sparse-check-out***

```
 git clone --depth 1 --filter=blob:none --sparse https:<repo_path>
 cd ./<local_repo_path>
 git sparse-checkout init --cone
 git sparse-checkout set <first_desired_folder>
```

I need to run something from the <first_desired_folder> above to decide what to **sparse-checkout further**

```
$VAR = ./<local_repo_path>/<first_desired_folder>/someprogram.py
```

***Second sparse-checkout***  is based on the $VAR above

```
git sparse-checkout set models/"$VAR-model"
```

I want to keep the **<first_desired_folder>** intact while doing the second sparse check-out above. The <local_repo_path> is only with models/$VAR-model and <first_desired_folder> disappears. How to achieve this serial sparse-checkouts keeping preserving both the folders.
I tried this
[configuring existing git repo for sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336810/configuring-existing-git-repo-for-sparse-checkout)
But it is not working.

One brute-force way is to sparse-checkout <first_desired_folder> along with models/$VAR-model in the second step but I was wondering if there is more elegant solution to this.

Comment: You want `git sparse-checkout add`, not `git sparse-checkout set`. The sparse checkout code is evolving now so you may need to update your Git version to get some of the newest features; if you don't have `git sparse-checkout add`, it's in a newer Git release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is THANKS to @torek.

In the second sparse-checkout instead of ***set***, we should be using ***add***

```
git sparse-checkout add models/"$VAR-model"
```

This works very well.