# Does git 'skipworktree' prevents the files to be updated from git pulls

Tags: git, version-control

I want a specific config file in my project to be have different configs in the local environment than to the prod environment  and I don't want to change or stash/pop the file every time I push something to the main repository

I found out that  using  :

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file>
```

lets me do exactly that.

I have one question though , In a scenario where someone else changes the config file and pushes the changes to the main repositary and the next time I pull the changes would my local config file be updated?

Comment: It does not, but [setting up sparse checkout does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37066742/2303202)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the config file is useless to do version control (since you need to config differently in local) you'd better ignore the file in `.gitignore`:

```
touch .gitignore
echo <file> >> .gitignore
git rm <file> --cached
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

The reason why not use `git update-index --skip-worktree <file>` as below:

- The config file is not changed locally, but only updated in remote, when you execute `git pull`, the config file will be update as remote.
- The config file both changed in local and remote, when you execute `git pull`, git will detect conflict and shows error as:

> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>         file
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
> Aborting
> ```

- The config file only changed locally, when you want to checkout other branches, git will show

> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>         file
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
> Aborting
> ```

- `git update-index --skip-worktree` is usually for temporarily use.

You can also compare the usage of `git update-index --skip-worktree` [here](http://blog.stephan-partzsch.de/how-to-ignore-changes-in-tracked-files-with-git/).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, this has got me confused though as I had assume marking a file as skip-worktree would make it be ignore by git pulls and branch checkouts .

If this is the case I don't understand the utility of git update-index --skip-worktree

Comment: Skip-worktree pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead. But when you use `git pull` or `git checkout branch`, the current index is trying to be discard, so skip-worktree will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is a little unclear here; in my tests (using version 2.12.0.windows.1) I am unable to pull if the remote contains changes to a file I've marked with `--skip-worktree`.  (I get the usual error for operations that would overwrite local changes.  I tried various ways to resolve this, but the only one that worked was to clear the skip-worktree bit, which of course would put you back to square one on protecting the local changes.)

Personally I think this solution is pretty messy.  You might be better off arranging things so that either (a) environment-specific settings are not source controlled (i.e. stored at paths covered by `.gitignore` or that are outside the repo), or (b) you keep versions of the files for each environment and the means of selecting the "active" one is not source controlled.

Comment: I can't gitignore the file . 

Right now I am stashing my local file everything I pull and poping the stash back once the pull is done . But I wished I could do this in a easier way

Comment: Well, if you insist on relying on manual procedures to avoid committing changes that you mean to be local, it is only a matter of time between failures.  Oh, but you're good enough to never make a mistake?  Cool.  Is everyone you work with (or ever will)?  Look, I don't care what you do with your repo, but don't ask a question and then pooh pooh what is in fact the correct way of handling the problem.  (Did you notice the other answer is actually giving exactly the same advice?)