# How to checkout git branch with local 'assume-unchanged' files?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, version-control, git-checkout

I've checked out from a remote branch and modified some of the files. However I do not wish to add them in the next commit since they are applicable only to my local configuration; in fact, I always want them to be uncommitted. For that reason, I've applied `git update-index --assume-unchanged` on these files. However, now I have problems with checking out from branches where these files differ from my local ones:
[image]

If I click on 'Smart Checkout' (which is what I need), it throws an error:

> Couldn't checkout origin/master: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

Even if I click on "Force Checkout" it will throw:

> Couldn't checkout origin/master: Entry '.gitignore' not uptodate. Cannot merge.

So how can I check out from other branches, while keeping local changes?

Comment: As for .gitignore you can add local ignore patterns to .git/info/exclude and keep the one in project unchanged

Comment: and by the way what you rather need is [skip-worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/2303202)

Comment: Looks like skip-worktree is the thing I was initially looking for. Please consider making that an answer, so that I could accept it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it and it seems to be a bit complecated. What I made to work I apparently [have already written once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37066742/2303202). So adding another same answer is probably not good.

Answer (score 2):

I always steer people away from `assume-unchanged`, for exactly this reason.  Your best bet is to find a different way to keep your changes out of the repo.

From your error message, it seems the `.gitignore` file is one of the files in question.  Non-shared/local ignore rules don't belong in `.gitignore`; they belong in `.git/info/exclude`.

Other cases may have to be dealt with individually.  A common case would be local config files. A typical solution is to source-control only a template, with the expectation that developers will create the actual config file locally (at a path that's either ignored or outside the repo work tree).

If you have local/unshared versions of code, I'd start by revisiting the reasons for that. If it's necessary, then the best solution may be to use a build process that lets you swap in code from outside the worktree.

The bottom line is, if you've told git to track the file at a path, it's going to try to do just that.

Comment: The reason I'm bothering with all these ceremonies is that I just want to send bug-fixing pull requests to various GitHub repositories, without committing any other modifications (like build.gradle files in this case). So is there a more convenient way to do that?

Comment: I think I would do it by making bugfixes I intend to share on branches rooted at the upstream (presumably checked out to a separate worktree), which I would then merge back into my own work lines.

Answer (score 1):

To checkout the other branch, Git needs to know about the changes, for each file:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged EACH_FILE
```

Stash those changes:

```
git stash save "Save local conf"
```

You can now checkout to your other branch:

```
git checkout myotherbranch
```

Finally, you can restore your local changes if you want them in your other branch:

```
git stash pop
```

And, as mentioned by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45190772/5118339), I'd use --skip-worktree to protect those files from changes. Why? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree)