# Ignore one line in a specific file in Git

Tags: git

I have a file `database.properties` which has

```
        password = something
```

So whenever I have to test something I will have to change this line to my local password. Everybody in the team will have their own local password.

I guess I will have to do one of the following :

1. Every time I commit I should not add `database.properties` to
   index (I don't want to `ignore` this file), but when there are too
   many files it's easy to miss this file.
2. Undo the changes before committing, but most of the time I forget
   to do this.
3. Creating a profile may be a way to achieve this but even will have similar issues as `database.properties`.

I have checked [Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line) and [How to tell git to ignore individual lines, i.e. gitignore for specific lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of).

From [temporarily ignoring files](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html) I see that we can do

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

but I will have to do this every time.

**All the above references were asked/written before 3-4 years.** So I just want to know If there is a better way to ignore just that one line.

**EDIT**

Following @VonC's answer I have tried to add a filter in `.git/info/.gitattribute`

```
{directory_path}/database.properties filter=password // I have given the correct directory path.
```

And I have added `smudge` and `clean` scripts as:

```
git config --global filter.password.smudge ~/smudge.sh 
git config --global filter.password.clean ~/clean.sh
```

(When I run `~/smudge.sh` and `~/clean.sh` it replaces `password= something` line correctly. So the scripts are correct.)

But when I add/commit the `database.properties`, there seems to be no affect on `database.properties` file. (I am guessing `~/clean.sh` should run when I add it to index)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stand by my 2014 answer in "[Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171275/6309)": a git content filter is made to change a line of a file by another content.

It still requires a (one time) `git config` command in order to declare that filter in your repo, but it will remain active (as oppose to a [`git update-index`, which can be discarded on, for instance, a `git reset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816844/6309))

The filter is associated to files in a `.gitattributes` file, put in the same folder as the `database.properties`. ([see discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87231/discussion-between-reservoir-sampling-and-vonc))
It is associated to a program to execute in the local config of the repo.

Comment: I have checked your answer but I was not very clear with it. `even though there are changes in filec.rb (in your example), it  will be considered as if it is not changed`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ReservoirSampling yes, the idea is to have a clean filter which restores the original content.

Comment: what about changes other than `password = something` (in `database.properties`)? Will I be able to commit and push them?

Comment: Only if your clean filter detects them as changes which needs to be kept intact (and not restored to the original content)

Comment: I have edited the question. I have tried adding filter but it does not seem to work. Could you check once?

Comment: @ReservoirSampling did you mention the full path of `database.properties` (by the way, don't use .git/info/.gitattribute, use a .gitattributes file in the database.properties folder)? or just the relative path from the root folder of the repo? Try it with just database.properties in `.gitattributes`, just for testing. Add, commit, then clone that repo and check how the now clone behaves itself regarding `database.properties`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87231/discussion-between-reservoir-sampling-and-vonc).

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach is to copy `database.properties` to `database.properties.in` and edit the latter to replace the password by a placeholder. Add `database.properties` (but not `database.properties.in`) to your `.gitignore` file.

Next you will need to write a small script to copy `database.properties.in` to `database.properties` and fill in the correct password. This script can be part of your build infrastructure (to be run after `database.properties.in` has changed) or you can set it up as a post-commit [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).