# using git to selectively push certain files but then I can't checkout another branch

Tags: git, github

I changed a few files in my local branch. I only want to push one file to origin. So I added, committed, and merged  and pushed only that file to the origin. Now, I want to checkout another branch to do work in there. But git says that since I have uncommitted modified files I can't checkout another branch. What should I do when I want to checkout another branch but don't want to add all my changed files to origin?

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- stash them ([`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))
  (you will apply that stash later when you come back to that branch),
- or commit them in your original branch before checkout the other one.
  Committing them won't mean you are pushing them right away,
- or create a temporary branch and commit them in that new branch (that you can merge later to your original branch),
- or, with git 2.5+, checkout another branch with the same repo.
  See [Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)

  ```
  git worktree add <path> [<anotherbranch>]
  ```

The last way allows you to have two different folders (for two different branches), and the same repo.
You switch between branch just by changing your current working directory (`cd`)

---

> what if I don't want them to ever be added to origin and they're just for my personal use on my local branch?

Then it is an entirely *different* question:

You can either:

- remove them from history (git rm --cached) and add them to your .gitignore.
  (but once pushed, those files will be gone for others as well)
- or you can [ignore the changes locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816844/6309)

  ```
  git update-index --skip-worktree -- path
  ```

Then any local modification would not show up in `git status`.
That is purely local to your repo, and is not pushed.

Comment: when I commit them, does that mean when I do a push later, they'll be added?

Comment: what if I don't want them to ever be added to origin and they're just for my personal use on my local branch? is git stash the best option in this case?

Comment: @coderk I am not aware of "git cache": "git stash" is the closest of "caching" (putting away) those files. But in your case, `git update-index --skip-worktree -- path` is an appropriate solution.