# GitLab - ignore specific files in target branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, merge-strategy

I am using GitLab in my project and I have a quite specific workflow. I have 2 branches "**Dev**" and "**Release**" as shown below. When I submit a merge request from Dev to Release, the config files are also getting overwritten with that of Dev branch.

[image]

But ideally config files have to be different for both of these branches. I tried to use `merge=ours`. But it didn't serve my purpose as it will not override until and unless there is a conflict in config files. I don't want to add these files in `.gitignore`, as any changes to these files will not be committed in **Dev** branch. Can someone please guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make sure your config files for dev and master are named differently, with their own history. That way, a merge will never overwrite anything.

You can then version and track:

- a `config.tpl` (template file with placeholder values).
- two config file, one for dev, one for master
- a script able to take a config file and a template file, and produce the `config` file (which remains untracked, private)
- a `.gitignore` which ignores the resulting generated `config` file
- a `.gitattribute` declaring a smudge content filter (see below)

The generation of the config file is automated through a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumAc.png]
<sup>(image from ["Customizing Git - Git Attributes"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)"))</sup>

Once you declare that content filer driver in your local config, it will automatically, on `git checkout`, generate your `config` file for you.
See a complete example in "[Best practice - Git + Build automation - Keeping configs separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309)".

Comment: Thanks a ton Vonc.