# Can git-stash ignore modifications to a tracked file

Tags: git, ignore, git-stash

I am working on a project which has a bit of an uncommon behaving thing:

One of the files in the source code is a file that contains serious code, but it can edit itself to also include some configuration. Whether this is good design is a different discussion, but to be able to test my project, this file needs to be in its modified state.

Before I commit anything, I normally do an A-B comparison between the situation before and after my  contribution. I use `git stash` to switch between base and my dirty working copy. The problem is that when using `git stash`, it also reverts my config-thing.

My current workaround is cumbersome: I do a `git add path/to/settingsfile` and then `git stash --keep-index`, but I rather dislike this workaround. Is there a  more elegant solution to have git ignore all modifications to this file unless I specify otherwise?

Comment: You really should fix that self-editing beast , or you are not going to win this battle.

Comment: Automatically generated content should be kept in a separate, untracked file. Sorting that out will immediately solve your problems, and make everything much cleaner.

Comment: Guys, I totally agree. Both +1, but note the reason that I mentioned that it's a different discussion, is that that's not supposed to be my fix, and to get it fixed, it should pass the usual bureaucracy. Eventually, if my boss / team mates want it this way or just don't care about my issue, I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See " [Preserve git --assume-unchanged files between branch checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815416/preserve-git-assume-unchanged-files-between-branch-checkouts/9816844#9816844) "

```
 git update-index --skip-worktree -- path
```

That wouldn't be reverted from a `git stash`.

---

Original answer

From "[temporarily ignoring files](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html) ":

```
 git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

That would allow to ignore changes to that specific files.
This won't help if you want to revert code changes *while* keeping config changes in the same file though.

And git stash will still revert it: [How to prevent git stash dropping changes to files with the "assume unchanged" bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962456/how-to-prevent-git-stash-dropping-changes-to-files-with-the-assume-unchanged-b)

---

Note that, before Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "[`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) save" in a working tree that is sparsely checked out mistakenly removed paths that are outside the area of interest.

See [commit 4a58c3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a58c3d7f7a83ebcd4ede635871cab7be24f7f3f), [commit 8dfb04a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8dfb04ae964868dda758997e5e7da29edff6164b) (30 Oct 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 57b5301](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57b530125e022de79f5f0b208bc0a5ee67c18b77), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a58c3d7f7a83ebcd4ede635871cab7be24f7f3f): handle staged changes in skip-worktree files correctly
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> When calling `git stash` while changes were staged for files that are marked with the `skip-worktree` bit (e.g. files that are excluded in a sparse checkout), the files are recorded as *deleted* instead.
>
> The reason is that `git stash` tries to construct the tree reflecting the worktree essentially by copying the index to a temporary one and then updating the files from the worktree.
>   Crucially, it calls `git diff-index` to update also those files that are in the HEAD but have been unstaged in the index.
>
> However, when the temporary index is updated via `git update-index --add --remove`, skip-worktree entries mark the files as deleted by mistake.
>
> Let's use the newly-introduced `--ignore-skip-worktree-entries` option of `git update-index` to prevent exactly this from happening.
>
> Note that the regression test case deliberately avoids replicating the scenario described above and instead tries to recreate just the symptom.
>
> Reported by Dan Thompson.

Comment: It looks promising when looking at the output of `git status`, but it seems `git stash` doesn't respect that. It still reverts the file back to BASE.

Comment: @PelletenCate yeap, I just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962456/how-to-prevent-git-stash-dropping-changes-to-files-with-the-assume-unchanged-b I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @PelletenCate to test: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9816844/6309 `git update-index --skip-worktree -- /path/to/file`: would `git stash` leave it alone then?

Comment: Yes, it does! :) For now, it seems to do exactly what I want it to do.  Thanks a million! (Incidentally, in your answer you linked to, it seems you state that they both options get reset when the index is discarded, e.g. on a reset. Isn't discarding the index what 'stash' does as well? :) ) I'll accept your answer. Maybe you could merge the solution in.

Comment: @PelletenCate I have updated the answer to make the solution more visible. I am guessing `git stash` doesn't exactly "reset the index" the way `git reset` does.